# Getting Generic failure while creating cluster with two node using WMI

Tags: c#, wmi

Please help.. I am trying to create a cluster with two nodes (both of them are server 2008) and I am running this C# application from windows 7. while creating I am getting the following exception ..

`Unhandled Exception: System.Management.ManagementException: Generic failure
   at System.Management.ManagementException.ThrowWithExtendedInfo(ManagementStat
us errorCode)
   at System.Management.ManagementObject.InvokeMethod(String methodName, Managem
entBaseObject inParameters, InvokeMethodOptions options)
   at Test.main.Main() in D:\Abhijit\Sandbox\BatonInstallerProject\BIM\windows\s
ource\test\main.cs:line 202`

```
public void CreateCluster(String[] NodeNames, String ClusterName, String ClusterIP)
{
    string[] ipaddresses = new string[1];
    string[] subnetmasks = new string[1];
    subnetmasks[0] = "255.255.255.0"; 
    ipaddresses[0] = ClusterIP;
    ManagementPath mgmtPath = new ManagementPath("MSCluster_Cluster");
    ObjectGetOptions objGetOptions = new ObjectGetOptions();
    ManagementClass mgmtClass = new ManagementClass(conn.GetConnectionScope, mgmtPath, objGetOptions);
    ManagementBaseObject inParams = mgmtClass.GetMethodParameters("CreateCluster");
    inParams["ClusterName"] = ClusterName;
    inParams["NodeNames"] = NodeNames;
    inParams["IPAddresses"] = ipaddresses;
    inParams["SubnetMasks"] = subnetmasks;
    ManagementBaseObject retVal = mgmtClass.InvokeMethod("CreateCluster", inParams, null);
}
```

After checking the enumaration type of the errorCode of ManagementException it was showing "Failed" .. I any one has any solution please share it I am stuck into it for couple of days ...

Comment: You should code format that-- select it all and press the code button in the formatting options. (Looks like two curly braces)